Save edited image to storage in compose coil
I want to rotate and zoom an image with sliders and save the edited image to storage in Android how can I do it?
Please let me know if this solution is not suitable.
  var sliderRotation by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(1f) }
    var sliderZoom by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(1f) }
  val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
            .build()
 Scaffold(
              modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
              topBar = {
                  MainToolbar(title = R.string.edit_image)
              }
          ) { paddingValue ->
              Column(
                  modifier = Modifier
                      .fillMaxSize()
                      .padding(paddingValue),
                  verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                  horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
              ) {

                  Box(
                      modifier = Modifier
                          .fillMaxWidth()
                          .weight(1f)
                  ) {

                      AsyncImage(
                          modifier = Modifier
                              .fillMaxSize()
                              .scale(sliderZoom)
                              .rotate(sliderRotation),
                          contentDescription = "Zoomable image",
                          model = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
                              .data(uiState.editImageUri.toString())
                              .build(),
                          imageLoader = imageLoader,
                      )

                }


                Column(
                     modifier = Modifier
                         .fillMaxWidth()
                         .weight(1f),
                     verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
                 ) {
                     SliderRow(
                         sliderValue = sliderRotation,
                         onValueChange = {
                             sliderRotation = it },
                         title = stringResource(R.string.size)
                     ) {
                         Icon(
                             painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.repeat),
                             contentDescription = "repeat icon",
                             tint = Color.Unspecified
                         )
                     }
                     SliderRow(
                         sliderValue = sliderZoom,
                         onValueChange = { sliderZoom = it },
                         title = stringResource(R.string.zoom)
                     ) {
                         Icon(
                             painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.repeat),
                             contentDescription = "repeat icon",
                             tint = Color.Unspecified
                         )
                     }

                    Button(onClick = { }) {
                    }
                 }
            }
        }


As far as I know Coil can only load and display images. It has some basic transformation options, but it is not made for image editing or even saving.

@Leviathan What do suggest to do this?

Haven't done anything like that, I would've to search for myself. However, such requests are off-topic on StackOverflow, sorry.

when using coil you can get the image result as bitmap and this bitmap can be saved anywhere in the file storage, for example:-
private fun Context.saveToInternalStorage(bitmapImage: Bitmap): String {
    val cw = ContextWrapper(applicationContext)
    val directory: File = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val mypath = File(directory, "profile.jpg")
    var fos: FileOutputStream? = null
    try {
        fos = FileOutputStream(mypath)
        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        try {
            fos!!.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    return directory.absolutePath
}

Edited:- Use can use SubcomposeAsyncImage to get the callback and once its success you can easily get the bitmap objec.
For more customization you have a look on the official documentation
SubcomposeAsyncImage(
    model = "https://example.com/image.jpg",
    contentDescription = "",
    onSuccess = {
       val bitmap =  it.result.drawable.toBitmap()
    },
    onError = {

    }
)


My question is which coil callback returns edited btmap?

I have edited my answer, how can you get the bitmap object from coil lib.
Please accept and upvote if its helps you.
Thanks.
